# Why doesn't formatting work in comments (for me)?

Tags: support, comments, formatting

I tried commenting on an answer, and all of my paragraphs were strung together in a single paragraph.

I used proper markdown, adding two spaces at the end of each paragraph.  When that didn't work, I tried appending a `<br/>` to the end of my paragraphs, but that didn't work either!  (In fact, the `<br/>` was rendered in my answer, instead of being interpreted as HTML.)

What was I doing wrong?

If it's relevant, my comment can be found here: [Can a Mac's model year be determined with a Terminal Command?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98080/can-a-macs-model-year-be-determined-with-a-terminal-command/298915#298915)

Comment: I haven’t seen paragraphs in comments. I don’t think it can be done either.

Answer (score 6):

You're doing nothing wrong; comments only support a [very specific subset of Markdown formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77491/295232) and this is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20591/295232). Which commands are supported is revealed when you click the 'help' link when posting a comment:

[image]

There's also a nice list of [shorthand links](https://apple.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) you can exclusively use in comments (they won't work in posts).